# Java - null instanceof Object evaluates to both true and false

Tags: java, instanceof

When I compile and run this code:

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Object obj = null;
        if (obj instanceof Object) {
            System.out.println("returned true"); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("returned false"); 
        }
        System.out.println(" " + obj instanceof Object);
    }
}
```

I get this on the command line:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop>java Testing
returned false
true
```

Shouldn't "null instanceof someType" always return false?

Comment: A similar puzzle; When is `x + 0 != x` ? BTW you expect the `+` to have higher precedence.

Comment: BTW: You could have become suspicious when java printed true and not <blank>true

Comment: I think the title is a bit misguiding, unless this were Java Quantum Edition and `instanceof` returned a quboolean.

Comment: @Peter - when X is double/float NaN, or any string.

Comment: @bestsss Being pedantic, you can have `double x` and `Double x` etc. ;)

Comment: @Peter, that also reminds me some obfuscated stuff like: what prints `System.out.println( 0-0x1.0p-1022<0);`

Comment: Another favourite is `x == -x` is true has 16 type/value combinations for `x` ;)

Comment: you must bue using Java, Schrödinger's Edition

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This:

```
" " + obj instanceof Object
```

is evaluated as:

```
(" " + obj ) instanceof Object
```

and `" " + obj` is indeed a non-null string which is an instance of `Object`.

Comment: This is a good lesson in "more parens are better than fewer when the operator precedence isn't blindingly obvious." `" " + (obj instanceof Object)` would have printed out the value you expected.

Comment: Good point. This is the kind of counter-intuitive behaviour you can study in _Java Puzzlers_ from Joshua Block and Neal Gafter.

Comment: @yshavit ... or use `String.valueOf(Object)` and not `"" + ...` when you want the String representation.

Comment: I just realized and refreshed and saw your answer :D

Comment: If you got it by yourself it's even better :)

Comment: @FabianBarney True, but the operator precedence bit applies more generally than just to this case (as does `String.valueOf`, of course). For instance, maybe you wanted to output a debug message, `"obj is a Foo? " + obj instanceof Foo`. Boolean logic is another good example: what does `a || b ? c : d` mean? Is it `(a || b) ? c : d` or `a || (b ? c : d)`? Parens (or better yet, named vars!) make that code a lot less tricky.

Comment: @yshavit, best thing is to learn and use debugger and step-in. (One would see the creation of the StringBuilder and the String). Although operator precedence MUST be known by heart by any programmer.

Comment: @bestsss I actually disagree on that last bit. If someone asked me what `a || b ? c : d` means, I'd tell them it means they should put in parens so that I don't have to memorize arcane sections of the JLS. :)

Comment: @yshavit, the result type of the operation is the same as `c` and `d`'s type.  Indeed if all a,b,c and d are booleans it'd be confusing from 1st sight. Adding parenthesis is strongly advisable since it improves the readability, yet not knowing the result is no excuse. Ternary operator has lowest (beside assignment) priority (in all languages that support it and I can think of, so it's not just the JLS)

Comment: Thanks God, in Lisp, we don't have to think about operators precedence.

Answer (score 2):

In the last `System.out.println`, the `" " + obj` evaluates first and the result, which is a `String` is checked for the `instanceof Object` and the result is printed.

Answer (score 2):

In (" " + obj) is the part which gets evaluated first so its no more null after parenthesis.
So it is the instance of Object.

Also refer the below link so your concept will be clear.

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html